# Trying to create a shell script to rename .jpg extension to the word front of all the directories in the current directory

Tags: bash, shell

```
#!/bin/bash

# Iterate through each .jpg file in the current directory
for file in *.jpg; do
  # Rename the file by adding "front" to the beginning of the name
  mv "$file" "front-$file"
done
```

But after the command I keep getting the error  No such file or directory

```
~/Music$ find . -name '*.jpg' | while read file; do ( mv "$file" "front-$file" ); done
mv: cannot move './dog.jpg' to 'front-./dog.jpg': No such file or directory
```

Comment: The script and the command are not the same. And the error message is quite clear, what part of it do you not understand or agree with?

Comment: Let me explain. I'm attempting to rename every ".jpg" extension to the word "front", regardless of  whats its named. I'm new to shell, so please forgive me if I misunderstand the language. I'm trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Assuming you want help with the `find`-based command, then (what is that script doing in the question?!): `"front-$file"` results in `front-./dog.jpg` and the target directory `front-.` does not exist, that’s what `mv` is complaining about.

Comment: The script is suppose to find .jpg files and just rename them to front.jpg so I'm guessing im telling it to find front instead of finding the files extension name

Comment: And what is wrong with the script?

Comment: Its not renaming the files with the extension .jpg to front.jpg so what part in the code I should change to have it do that. I'm asking the script to find .jpg files and rename them to front.jpg for instance if the file name is cover.jpg I'm asking the code to name to name it to front.jpg

Comment: I don’t understand. Your title says one thing, then comes a script that does something else, but no word on whether the script works or how it fails, then a command that does something similar but fails with a clear message, then your comments say you want to do something different still. Either I just don’t get it or your question could use some clarification, e.g. examples of files before and after whatever it is you want to do.

Comment: The script looks fine, but you get an error after `~/Music$ find . ...`, so the `find` command fails, not the script with `for`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The files returned by `find .` command start with `./` token.

With `mv "$file" "front-$file"`, destination files start with `front-./` token.

`mv` search a directory named `front-.`. If it's not exists, the command exit with an error code and the associated message.

Replace `"front-$file"` by `"${file%/*}/front-${file##*/}"`.

Explanations:

- `${file%/*}` remove last right part (part are separated by a `/`) of the filename
- `${file##*/}` remove all parts from the left, except the last, of the filename

Example:

```bash
> file="./the/file/path/file.jpg"
> echo "${file%/*}/front-${file##*/}"
./the/file/path/front-file.jpg
```

Comment: That worked thanks I understand what I did wrong now. I'm still learning